# ERROR Woocommerce ajustes pagina de la tienda

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

Estoy montando una web de cursos online con woocomerce, el problema es que en ya tengo mi propia forma de mostrar los productos (en mi caso cursos) y cuando modifico los ajustes de woocommmerce `ajustes>productos>pagina de la tienda` y guardo, modifica la pagina de la tienda poniendo un bloque de `CSS` y el titulo, en concreto pone esto:

```
Course list

/*! elementor – v3.11.3 – 07-03-2023 */
.elementor-heading-title{padding:0;margin:0;line-height:1}.elementor-widget-heading
.elementor-heading-title[class*=elementor-size-]>a{color:inherit;font-size:inherit;line-
height:inherit}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-
small{font-size:15px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-
medium{font-size:19px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-
large{font-size:29px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-
xl{font-size:39px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-
xxl{font-size:59px}

-- RESTO DE LA WEB
```

no existiria ninguna forma de solucionarlo o de modifcar los archivos para solucionarlo?
Pasa lo mismo con todas las paginas, anula todo el css existente en la pagina e imprime ese bloque de css.

Comment: Cuando se trata de plugins externos es muy difícil ayudar con código, en tu caso elementor esta modificando el diseño de los productos de woocommerce, sin un [example] no podemos ayudarte, porque no sabemos exactamente qué esperas lograr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final el problema resulto ser un conflicto de plugins, la plantilla está hecha con elementor por lo que seleccionar en los ajustes de woocomerce una página hecha con elementor este modifico la página haciendo él css de elementor se anulara y lo pusiera como texto.

La solución terminó siendo añadir la siguiente función en el archivo **functions.php** del tema:

```
function wc_empty_cart_redirect_url() {
return 'http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/courses-list-origin/';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', 'wc_empty_cart_redirect_url' );
```

Puede que no sea la forma más ortodoxa, pero es lo que me funciona.